Agnoster broken with latest MacOS
I don't know why but it's been a few weeks that I have an issue with the Agnoster theme, which is the main reason why I am favouring oh-my-zsh over other shells.
Basically:

it doesn't show the / between the folder
it's not highlighting the branch in yellow
it's not showing any icon at all
terminal

I did install patched Powerline fonts and using Meslo LG Powerline. The shell is updated as well.
Instead, the default Robbyrussel theme works like a charm, but I don't like it.
Just so you know, I use Tabby as terminal.
Is this happening to anyone else?

Updating the shell
Updating the terminal app
Updating fonts

I expect only the normal visualization of the theme.

Fixed installing powerlevel10k.

I was having the same issue, until I did a little more digging.
If you're not using a compatible terminal app, you need to, rather than the built-in Mac app. I'm using iTerm 2.
Once you have it installed, you can go to settings -> profiles, check the 'non-ASCII fonts' selection and choose one of the powerline fonts (I chose Go Mono for Powerline).
After all this, it should be working as expected.
